# Thumbnail seeking feature in video players

Tags: video, vlc, video-player

YouTube (and many other online video streaming websites) has a nifty feature. If you place the mouse cursor at any point on the video progress bar at the bottom of the video, a thumbnail pops up showing a preview of the frame of the video (approximately) at the second where the cursor is placed.

[image]
([video source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sk9TatW9ino))

I use *SMPlayer* and *VLC* to play videos and also have "*Videos*" (aka `totem`) installed by default.

- Is there any settings/plug-ins/extensions/add-ons available for any of the above mentioned video players to enable a similar "*thumbnail-seeking*" feature?
- Alternatively, is there a video playing application (free or non-free) available for Ubuntu which supports enabling this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try [ExMplayer](http://exmplayer.sourceforge.net/), a graphical front-end for MPlayer.  It comes with a thumbnail seeking feature.

You can install ExMplayer from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~exmplayer-dev/+archive/ubuntu/exmplayer) by running the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:exmplayer-dev/exmplayer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install exmplayer
```

Comment: I know ;) Why don't you expand your answer a bit? Maybe add the installation process too.

Answer (score 1):

There is such an application it is called ExMplayer. You can check out the page for the ppa [Here](https://launchpad.net/~exmplayer-dev/+archive/ubuntu/exmplayer). Also here is the link to the Website  for [Exmplayer](http://exmplayer.sourceforge.net/index.html)